# Android: How to put ListView in XML?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I want to make a simple app that shows a list of contacts (name, surname). My code:

```
package lista.android;

import java.util.*;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

class Contact{
    String nume;
    String prenume;

    Contact(String nume, String prenume){
        this.nume=nume;
        this.prenume=prenume;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return prenume +" "+ nume;
    }
}

public class Lista1Activity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ArrayList <Contact> lista;
    ArrayAdapter <Contact> adaptor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(adaptor);

        lista=new ArrayList<Contact>();
        adaptor=new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this, R.id.element, lista);

        adaugaContact("Florian", "Iancu");
        adaugaContact("Ioana", "Constantina");

    }

    public void adaugaContact(String nume, String prenume){
        lista.add(new Contact(nume, prenume));
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

In the XML I have the `LinearLayout` and a `TextView` that is the list element. When I run it, the simulator says `"Sorry, the application [...] has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."` The LogCat tells me I have to have a `ListView` whose id is android.R.id.lista. If I create a random `ListView` field in the XML file and give it the "lista" id, it still doesn't work. How to I call that ListView from XML to match something in my Java code? In other words, I know I'm wrong, but where and how do I fix it?

Comment: You are trying to set List Adapter first and then creating it. Don't you think this is the wrong!!

Comment: You need to understand the concept of creating listview first i think.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the LinearLayout you have to specify the ListView component.

This is how your **main.xml** should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sampleListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#CCCCCC"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then for the listview make a layout: **list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    android:padding="10dp"    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Change your **activity class** like this:

```
public class Lista1Activity extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<Contact> lista;
    ArrayAdapter<Contact> adaptor;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lista = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    adaugaContact("Florian", "Iancu");
    adaugaContact("Ioana", "Constantina");

     adaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, lista);

    setListAdapter(adaptor);
    }

    public void adaugaContact(String nume, String prenume) {
    lista.add(new Contact(nume, prenume));
    adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: As I stated, I have tried adding a listview field in my XML, but it has to be tied to my Java code. Where do I tie to it and how do I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so you suggest instantiating "adaptor" before using it. It's a good point, but it still doesn't work, same exception: "need to have a listview whose id is android.R.id.list".
The documentation says something about ListView lv = getListView();
How do I get that one into my code?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Since you have extended a ListActivity, **ListView lv = getListView();** would instantiate the ListView in your activity.

Comment: You can use list item designs provided by the platform instead of defining your own layout file (list_item.xml
) for the ListAdapter. For example, try using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 instead of R.layout.list_item.

Comment: And I also should have overwritten the onListItemClick() function.
Thanks for your time and answers! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight=".5dpdp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As I stated, I have tried adding a listview field in my XML, but it has to be tied to my Java code. Where do I tie to it and how do I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

It sounds like you need to take a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) again.

It is very well described there.